# Managing Httpcache from C# using JSON configuration

Tags: c#, json, http, caching

I have written an efficient way to control data to be cached/not-cached in HttpCache using JSON and C# controlling it.

The reason for this implementation is to make use of existing application servers to store cache to save network latency and call across processes. another reason was to minimize code change after we find memory or performance issues (as you can control data from JSON).

The implementation uses C# code to interact with HttpCache and uses JSON object to find what to cache in a similar way we have seen form authentication used to work in web application projects.

The JSON format looks like:

```
{
  Key: "Cache",
  Allow: "*",
  Deny: "",
  Keys: [
    {
      Key: "CacheKey",
      Allow: "*",
      Deny: "",
      Keys: [
        {
          Key: "Organization",
          Allow: "*",
          Deny: "",
          Keys: [
            {
              Key: "Department",
              Allow: "*",
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      Key: "SomeOtherCacheKey",
      Allow: "*",
      Deny: ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am taking example of an `Employee` class which is searched by Organization and Department.

Although the solution is not fully dynamic, it works closely with repository.

To implement it, I have created a generic `CacheBase` class. This class must be derived from a facade that will be called to get data and the facade will call the `GetFromCache` method to get data from the cache. If it is not allowed by JSON to manage the cache for the given cacheKey along with the parameters (group keys and values), facade will call the repository directly. I am assuming that required parameter will be injected to constructor.

Edits and code review is welcome.

```
public class EmployeeFacade: CacheBase<IEnumerable<Employee>>
{
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository _repository;
    public EmployeeFacade(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository) : base("3600","Employee_Cache",cacheConfigurationJSON)
    {
        _repository = employeeRepository;
    }

  public method GetEmployee(string organization, string department)
  {
        var groupKeyAndValues = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        groupKeyAndValues.Add(new Tuple<String, string>("Organization", organization));
        groupKeyAndValues.Add(new Tuple<String, string>("Department", department));
        bool isCacheAllowed;

        var employeeInfos = base.GetFromCache(() => _repository.GetEmployee(organization, department), groupKeyAndValues, out isCacheAllowed);

        //if cache is not allowed for this combination , return direct from repository.
        if (!isCacheAllowed)
            return _repository.GetEmployee(organization, department);
  }
}

public abstract class CacheBase<T> where T : class
{
    private string _cacheTimeoutInSeconds;
    private string _cacheConfiguration;
    private static readonly object CacheLockObject = new object();
    string _cacheKey;
    public CacheBase(string cacheTimeoutInSeconds, string cacheKey, string cacheConfigurationJson)
    {
        _cacheTimeoutInSeconds= cacheTimeoutInSeconds;
        _cacheConfiguration = cacheConfigurationJson;
        _cacheKey = cacheKey;
    }

    public T GetFromCache(Func<T> methodToFillCache, IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> groupKeyAndValues, out bool isCacheAllowed)
    {
        var baseCacheKey = _cacheKey;
        var detailedCacheKey = GenerateCacheKey(groupKeyAndValues);
        isCacheAllowed = IsSaveToCacheAllowed(baseCacheKey, groupKeyAndValues);

        if (!isCacheAllowed) return null;

        var result = HttpRuntime.Cache[detailedCacheKey] as T;

        if (result == null)
        {
            lock (CacheLockObject)
            {
                if (result == null)
                {
                    result = methodToFillCache() as T;
                    SetToCache(result, detailedCacheKey);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void SetToCache(T data, string detailedCacheKey)
    {

        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(detailedCacheKey, data, null,
            DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(cacheTimeoutInSeconds)), TimeSpan.Zero);
    }

    private string GenerateCacheKey(IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> groupKeyAndValues)
    {
        string detailedCacheKey = _cacheKey;
        if (groupKeyAndValues == null) return detailedCacheKey;
        var groupKeys = groupKeyAndValues.Select(x => x.Item1).ToList();
        if (groupKeys != null && groupKeys.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var groupKey in groupKeys)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(groupKey))
                    detailedCacheKey += "_" + groupKey;
            }
        }
        return detailedCacheKey;
    }

    private bool IsSaveToCacheAllowed(string cacheKey, IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> groupKeyAndValues)
    {
        cacheKey = cacheKey.ToUpper();

        if (_cacheConfiguration == null) return false;

        string valuesAllowed = CacheConstant.All; string valuesDenied = CacheConstant.All;

        //CACHE                                                                 
        if (_cacheConfiguration == null) return true;
        valuesAllowed = _cacheConfiguration.Allow;
        valuesDenied = _cacheConfiguration.Deny;

        var matchingCacheConfig = _cacheConfiguration.Keys.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.ToUpper() == cacheKey);
        if (matchingCacheConfig == null) return IsAllowed(cacheKey, valuesAllowed, valuesDenied); ;
        valuesAllowed = matchingCacheConfig.Allow;
        valuesDenied = matchingCacheConfig.Deny;

        bool isAllowed = IsAllowed(cacheKey, valuesAllowed, valuesDenied);                                                                               
        foreach (var groupKeyAndValue in groupKeyAndValues)
        {
            var key = groupKeyAndValue.Item1.ToUpper();
            var value = groupKeyAndValue.Item2.ToUpper();
            matchingCacheConfig = matchingCacheConfig.Keys.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.ToUpper() == key);

            if (matchingCacheConfig == null) return IsAllowed(key, valuesAllowed, valuesDenied);
            valuesAllowed = matchingCacheConfig.Allow;
            valuesDenied = matchingCacheConfig.Deny;

            isAllowed = IsAllowed(value, matchingCacheConfig.Allow, matchingCacheConfig.Deny);

            if (!isAllowed) break;
        }
        return isAllowed;
    }

    bool IsAllowed(string value, string allowedValues, string deniedValues)
    {
        //Prerequisites: among allowed and denied values , one should contain * and other should contain value or empty string 
        var allowed = allowedValues.ToUpper().Split(',');
        var denied = deniedValues.ToUpper().Split(',');
        if (denied.Contains(CacheConstant.All))
        {
            if (allowed.Contains(value) || allowed.Contains(CacheConstant.All))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (denied.Contains(value))
        {
            if (allowed.Contains(value))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else //denied contains nothing
        {
            if (allowed.Contains(value) || allowed.Contains(CacheConstant.All) || allowed.Count() == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```